Finish build trigger is not firing for master branch
I have project A and project B, project B's build configuration has snapshot dependency on project A and 'Finish Build Trigger' depending on A. When I write +:* in branch filters it project B is triggered in case of project A's successful build, but when I change it to +:refs/heads/master (which is totally valid for my teamcity config) or +:refs/heads/* even, it fails
  (finish build trigger page)
But it fired in case when I set two finish build triggers (+:* and +:refs/heads/master simultaneously)
 (successfull run, and BTW it runs under name refs/heads/master as default branch in this case, if it had been set as only +:* the name would be master)

TeamCity version 2022.10
I thought that maybe it is not refs/heads/master but something else, and tried different names for branch filter, tried multiple triggers and so on
